# Sectional curvature to Ricci tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

We know that to measure the if the n-dimensional manifold is curved or not, we look at the Riemann Tensor. If it is 0, then it is flat otherwise it is curved positively or negatively (which each of the sign has its own geometric meaning).

Ricci tensor help us track the volume changes along when we move in the direction of a geodesic.

We know the well known method of contracting the indices gives us the direct result from Riemann tensor to Ricci tensor. But this doesn't gives a meaning of what does it means geometrically. So we us Sectional Curvature.

Sectional curvature (K) helps us understand geometrically that whether the geodesics are converging, diverging or remains flat when we move along a direction of vector 'v'. '

So Ricci Tensors are derived by selecting direction 'v' and summing over all possible Sectional Curvatures containing the vector 'v'.

I am having a problem deriving the Ricci tensor from Sectional curvature tensor. Any help would be grateful.

K = $v^j$$v^k$$[R(e_i,e_j)]e_k$.$e_i$ gives

$v^j$$v^k$$R^l$$_k$$_i$$_j$ $e_l$.$e_i$

Then

$v^j$$v^k$$R^l$$_k$$_i$$_j$ $g$$_l$$_i$

Finally,

$v^j$$v^k$$R$$_i$$_k$$_i$$_j$

Which upon summation on i gives

Ricci Tensor (Ric (v,v))= $v^j$$v^k$$R$$_k$$_j$

Which is a component of a ricci tensor..

here we can see that the lower indices of the Riemann Tensor are contracted which is wrong. The upper index and the lower middle index are contracted which is correct.

Please tell me the problem here.

Comment: Your first equation is problematic because it has two lower $i$’s.

Comment: @G.Smith this is what is the definition/method  to derive the Ricci Tensor form Sectional curvature tensor.

Comment: You asked why you ended up with two lower $i$’s. It’s because you started with them. If it’s wrong at the end (and it is) then it is wrong at the beginning. Contracting two lower or two upper indices does not produce a lower-rank tensor; it produces something useless. Only contracting one upper index with one lower index is valid.

Comment: If I put one of the basis vector as covector (making its index up) it looses the definition/meaning behind being a sectional curvature.

Do you know how to obtain Ricci tensor from sectional curvature?

Comment: No. When I learned GR we didn’t discuss sectional curvature.

Comment: Try making contact between your formula and [Wikipedia’s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sectional_curvature). (Why does yours have only one vector while Wikipedia’s has two?) What book are you using?

Comment: *otherwise it is curved positively or negatively* That’s misleading. The Riemann tensor has 256 components, 20 of which are independent. Some components can be positive while others are negative.

Comment: The Wikipedia formula is written more abstractly than yours but in index notation it would involve properly-contracted indices.